# Mongodb and Springboot return empty List for FindByAttribute

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, rest

I'm getting an empty list of objects upon the findByville method I've implemented.
This is My Controller:

```
@RestController
public class CatalogController {
    @Autowired
    CatalogService catServ;
 @RequestMapping(path="/findByVille",method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public  int findByVille(@RequestParam("ville") String ville){
     ArrayList<Catalog> CatList=new ArrayList<>();
     CatList=catServ.findByVille(ville);
     if(CatList==null){
        return -1;
     }
     return CatList.size();
 }
}
```

My model:

```
@Document(collection = "catalog")
public class Catalog {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String nom;
    private String address;
    private String ville;
    ArrayList<Categories> categories;

    public Catalog() {

    }
    public Catalog(String id, String nom, String address, String ville, ArrayList<Categories> categories) {
        this.id = id;
        this.nom = nom;
        this.address = address;
        this.ville = ville;
        this.categories = categories;
    }
//getters and setters
```

and my mongodb document

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5fb45837bf4f57b4a1effa30"},
"nom":"ElectroPlanet Massira","address":"18,avnmassira",
"ville":"Marrakech",
"categories":[{"nom":"Smartphones",
"produits":[{"reference":"LG-8X-PRO","libelle":"LG Gran","marque":"LG","price":1652.59,"stock":15,"image":"image/lg_phone_in_apretty_case.jpeg",
"dimension":{"longueur":12.56,"largeur":7.6,"hauteur":1},
"caracteristiques":["red","153g","Metal"],
"reviews":[{"nom":"anonymous","stars":2,"commentaire":"loreom ipsilom jdbf"}]}]},{"nom":"ElectroBeauty","produits":[{"reference":"BR-XLS-63","libelle":"Epilateur","marque":"Braun","price":350,"stock":26,"image":"image/braun_epilateur_electro.jpeg","dimension":{"longueur":0,"largeur":null,"hauteur":5.32},"carateristiques":["Batteries","Antibumps","Garanti 2 ans"],"reviews":[{"nom":"Sarah","stars":4,"commentaire":"Parfaite!"}]}]}]}
```

EDIT:***
My repository :

```
@Repository
public interface CatalogRepository extends MongoRepository<Catalog,String> {

    ArrayList<Catalog> findByVille(String ville);
    ArrayList<Catalog> findByCategories_Nom(String nom);
```

and this is what I get when I run the project:
[image: the result of the findByVille method]

Comment: Can you show your repository?

Comment: ah yes I added it.